# Dialog layout doesn't fit correctly - Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm currently working on an app that contains a list. In order to add items to that list, the user has a button in the action bar which on click, opens a dialog that contains a form. The user has to fill that form and click on the submit button.

Now, I created the form layout in a seperate xml file. The problem is whenever I inflate the dialog object inside the dialog fragment, when I run the app, the layout is not showed as expected. The margins between the edit texts are wrong. Moreover, the background tints of the edit texts, which are all defined to the same color inside my colors.xml file, are shown with different shades, which is unexplained. 
The weird thing is that in the layout editor in android studio, the preview image shows exactly what I want.

Here is the code of DialogFragment:

```
package com.silverfix.dgdeditor.fragments;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.silverfix.dgdeditor.R;

/**
 * Created by David on 17/11/2016.
 */

public class DangerousGoodDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DGDialogTheme);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dg_dialog, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is the xml code of the dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/dg_dialog_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/action_bar_background"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:elevation="22dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/action_bar_background"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_above="@id/imageView3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/dg_dialog_box_margin">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/un_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dg_dialog_box_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:hint="Field 1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/desc_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dg_dialog_box_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:hint="Field 2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/class_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dg_dialog_box_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:hint="Field 3" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/pack_group_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dg_dialog_box_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:hint="Field 4" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dg_dialog_box_margin"
            android:hint="Field 5" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/inst_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dg_dialog_box_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:hint="Field 6" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/auth_text"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorHint"
            android:hint="Field 7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

-- UPDATE: --

Here are the images of the layout.

Layout editor: https://i.gyazo.com/d4b9d0d56919eb9286dec3b1a29903c6.png

Virtual Device: https://i.gyazo.com/26c9f5399df51ed65ca2601210bcded2.png

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of what it's displaying?

Comment: I edited the post and added images

Comment: You can try this, in all your EditText element, change height from wrap_content to 0dp and add `weight` attribute to 1 in all EditText element and please remove all your `layout_below` and `layout_above` element from the EditText.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix the height problem with layout_weight=1 but the other problem remains. The background tints are shown in different shades, although all the edit texts use the same color resource

Comment: Can you update the code in your question so that I can see what's going wrong with the color.

Comment: I updated the code. You can take a look

Comment: I put the same code in my android studio and it's showing the same colors of the editText tints. So it's working fine in my case. You can change the color to colorPrimary to check if the things worked.

Comment: I tried to set the colors to colorPrimary but it still doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but it worked on my phone and I have the screenshot but don't know how to upload that in the comment section...